# Joining strings by ClientAPI.COLUMN_DELIMITER and then splitting by the same delimiter adds two new elements

Tags: c#, string, dotnetnuke

I have the following

`string.Join(ClientAPI.COLUMN_DELIMITER),(new string[] {"1", "2" })).Split(ClientAPI.COLUMN_DELIMITER.ToCharArray())`

I expect the result to be an array of length 2, instead two new empty strings are added.

Why does this happen and how can I avoid it in the Join method. (I have no control on Split).

[image: string join and split]

**EDIT**

[image]

Comment: [RemoveEmptyEntries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) when splitting

Comment: @AFriend, I have not control on the Split. Moreover the string[] *can* contain other empty strings which should not be removed.

Comment: I don't know what that means. And why not just split this out into more readable lines, and debug it yourself? Examine different values step by step.

Comment: What if the input array is `new string[] {string.Empty, "2" }` ? What the output array be? You are not answering my question, just giving a workaround.

Comment: Can you post potential (typical) values for the delimiters and input string?  Also, split the statement into individual lines to avoid silly things -- such as `new string(ClientAPI.COLUMN_DELIMITER.ToCharArray())`, which looks like you are converting a string to a character array and back to a string again.  Wasted effort, if that is indeed what you are doing -- difficult to tell with so little information and convoluted code.

Comment: Just separate each part into a new line so you can **debug it yourself**.

Comment: But, at a guess -- and without input values to evaluate, it can only be a guess -- by joining by a string (potentially more than one character), it will add all delimiters between each element.  Then the split will split on each delimiter producing empty elements between the delimiters as a result.  Make sure to only join on a single delimiter.

Comment: @DavidCulp I updated the question.

Comment: Why are you calling ToCharArray when splitting? Just do `input.Split(new[] {separator})`

Comment: What is the type of `ClientAPI.COLUMN_DELIMITER`?

Comment: @NetMage It is `string`. See more: http://api.dotnetnuke.ru/language/ru-ru/did/20271/doc.aspx

Comment: Then as @DavidCulp asked, why are you doing `new string(ClientAPI.COLUMN_DELIMITER.ToCharArray())` which is converting a string to a character array back to a string and accomplishes nothing useful?

Comment: Why can't you change the `Split`? The way the `Split` is written implicitly assumes a single character delimiter.

Comment: @NetMage Because it is used widely throughout an existing application, which I do not intend to change dramatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does this happen [..] ?

Documentation for the [String.Split Method (Char[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) tell us :

> Each element of separator defines a separate delimiter character. If two delimiters are adjacent, or a delimiter is found at the beginning or end of this instance, the corresponding element in the returned array contains Empty

That's why you've got empty string in your result array (not because of the Join method as you wrote in a comment).

EDIT:
With this example, Split method gives back your "input" array :

```
string.Join("~|~", new string[] { string.Empty, "2" }).Split(new string[] { "~|~" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

EDIT-2:
Try this :

```
string.Join(ClientAPI.COLUMN_DELIMITER, new string[] { string.Empty, "2" }).Split(ClientAPI.COLUMN_DELIMITER, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: Is there a workaround? I must keep the delimiter unchanged.

Comment: @user7518s I edited my answer. I hope it will help you.

Comment: I get the same exact result as before adding `StringSplitOptions.None`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your code is that you are giving the `String.Split` method a character array. Now it thinks you want to divide the original string at ANY of the given characters, in your case '~' and '|'.

Your test string was "~|~1", so he finds three delimiters: '~', '|' and '~' again. Three delimiters means four strings as a result, thus your three empty strings.

What you really intended to do was split by "~|~" as a full string, which you can accomplish by calling:

`joined_input.Split(new string[] { ClientAPI.COLUMN_DELIMITER }, StringSplitOptions.None)`

(Without .ToCharArray)

If you do not want to receive empty entries, you can also use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`

```
string.Join(new string(ClientAPI.COLUMN_DELIMITER.ToCharArray()), (new string[] { "1", "2" }))
.Split(ClientAPI.COLUMN_DELIMITER.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

**EDIT**

It is not possible to return original empty strings. Because, you don't know which one is original. Maybe you can replace empty strings before spliting it with a "pattern" and then replace with empty string back while restoring them.

```
string pattern = "emptystringpattern";
string seperator = "||";
string[] input = new string[] { string.Empty,"1" };
for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
{
    if (input[i] == string.Empty)
    {
        input[i] = pattern;
    }
}

string joinedInput = string.Join(seperator, input);
var splits = joinedInput.Split(seperator.ToCharArray(),StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

for (int i = 0; i < splits.Length; i++)
{
    if (splits[i] == pattern)
    {
        splits[i] = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Also, `pattern` should not contain the delimeter character.

Another option is that you can get count of the empty strings before splitting and after splitting process, you can add them the array again according to counting.

Comment: I must not remove empty entries, i just need to remove the ones added by the "Join" method. What would the result be if the input array is `new string[] {string.Empty, "2" }`

Comment: Why the "Join" add empty string, I couldn't understand. Please share the real output and expected output.

Comment: I updated the question. The expected output is obviously the input array.